# Google Analytics Interest API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

google analytics offers the interests of the users of my website. I was wondering, if there is a way for me to access ther interests of the current user with php. Is that a part of the google api?
I am asking this, because i am trying to find a way to deliver ads to the different users. I think it would be a great improvement if i could somehow find out what the user is interested in.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. If it's "does the Google API give me a way to determine the interests of the users of my website", that's something you could find from reading documentation. If it's "How can I deliver user-specific ads to my site's users, using the Google API", that a different question altogether. You've accepted an answer which doesn't really answer either of those questions completely, implying that you were interested in some subset of information. You may want to [edit] your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Analytics Reporting API V4

Yes it is possible to query the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) for the [audience dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=audience&jump=ga_interestothercategory). Try a sample query in the [Query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

#### User scoped custom dimension

You could use a [User Scoped Custom Dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-user) to identify the current user. Note: this would really only work for users who had previously visited your site. New users to your site would not yet have their data processed and populated.

#### Authentication

You would need to set up [service account authentication](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) for you php implementation. Remember to add the service account to the appropriate view you wish to query.

#### Implementation

Your web server would have to keep track the the current users custom dimension query the API for various interest dimensions and your chosen date range and metrics. From the response of the API you web application could then make a choice as to what types of advertisements to show the current user.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps me a lot. Do i understand it correctly that i can only use this on user that have been on my site before? Or can i at least use some part of it for new users as well?

Comment: Think of the user scoped custom dimension as a database key your application creates for each user (**no PII please!**). You are querying the Google Analytics data base for that database key and its associated dimensions and metrics. A new user gets a new key, thus there would be no information in the database yet because you are just now putting the data into the database.

Google Analytics is your data, your application sends data in, it gets processed and it is eventually available to be queried. Before you send data there is of course no data to be queried.